# django class view access response

Tags: django, django-views

in function view:

```py
def view(request):
    # do something with request
    response = render(request, 'view.html')
    # do something with response
    return response
```

but now I have a `View` class:

```py
class ArticleDeleteView(View):
    pass


# or even something more complicated
class ArticleDeleteView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, DeleteView):
    pass
```

which function shall I overwrite to access to the `response`?

---

sorry that it may seems a silly question to you, but I looked through the docs and failed to find an answer.

---

thanks for all suggestions in comment. here's why I need to access to the response. [Conditional Django Middleware (or how to exclude the Admin System)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1028019/conditional-django-middleware-or-how-to-exclude-the-admin-system)

I am building a specific type of 'middleware', for certain class based view, they are not actually middleware since they are not called for each request. I need to access to the response in order to **do something before and after the response** then return it, therefore I much would like to know which function generate response.

Comment: What do you want to do with `response` ?

Comment: Here is useful [site](https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/4.0) to inspect all available methods of a class.

Comment: For [**View**](https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/4.0/django.views.generic.base/View/), [**LoginRequiredMixin**](https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/4.0/django.contrib.auth.mixins/LoginRequiredMixin/), [**UserPassesTestMixin**](https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/4.0/django.contrib.auth.mixins/UserPassesTestMixin/), [**DeleteView**](https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/4.0/django.views.generic.edit/DeleteView/),

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest answer is: you don't. The View classes tend to be uncomplicated enough to be easily rewritten as a custom view which inherently gives you access to the response.

However if you insist I guess one of the functions you could override is the following: `as_view`, `dispatch` or `setup` as the request function goes through all of them. Sadly I couldn't find any mention of the one that was intended for that purpose.

Comment: cheers, I will have a go with `dispatch`